# worklight with android back button behavior

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I need your help, We are currently using worklight hybrids application and using sencha framework, we need to trigger when the user press the android back button. Actually that one i tried to get alert form my device after that i need to close the apps.
we are currently get alert for YES or NO confirm Message display on device. If i click Yes means i want close or minimize application. below that code i was tried. how to close apps using worklight API?

```
 if (Ext.os.is('Android')) {
                document.addEventListener("backbutton", Ext.bind(onBackKeyDown, this), false);
                function onBackKeyDown(eve) {
                    eve.preventDefault();

                    Ext.Msg.confirm('Test',"Are you Want Quit Application", function (btn) {
                        switch (btn) {
                            case 'yes':
                                    WL.Client.reloadApp(); // this is i am using but i dnt want this.
                                break;
                            default:
                                break;
                        }
                   });
                }
            }
```

Thanks
karthik E

Answer (score 2):

Quitting an app is no longer considered, in both Android and iOS, an action that should be done programmatically. It is an action that must be explicitly done by the end-user.

Meaning, after the app was "closed", the end-user must use the physical/software button that opens the list of apps and quit the application by swiping the application off the list.

This works:

```
function wlCommonInit(){
    WL.App.overrideBackButton(checkQuit());
}

function checkQuit() {
    WL.SimpleDialog.show(
            "Quit application", 
            "Are you sure?", 
            [
             {text: "Yes", handler: function() {WL.App.close();}},
             {text: "No", handler: function() {}}
             ]
    );
}
```